# How to change gradient settings for muliple equal objects at the same time?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, gradient

I have multiple objects with equal gradients in Adobe Illustrator. Anyone knows how can I change gradient settings for all of the objects at once?

Comment: Selecting them all, then editing in the Gradient Panel, doesn't work?

Comment: What @Scott said is true, assuming they all use the same gradient...

Comment: Scott or WELZ, could you make that into an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Edit -> Edit Colors -> Recolor Artwork. You can see all colors here and you can edit / replace them.

Answer (score 0):

For the future only: Drag an object to the Symbols panel. From there you can drag multiple instances of it to the artboard. Edit the original in the Symbols panel or one of the instances on the artboard. All instances will get the same edit including the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the gradient as you want on one instance;
2. Open the Graphic Styles palette (Window > Graphic Styles or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>;
3. Drag your correctly gradiented object into the palette to create a new Graphic Style;
4. Select all other objects;
5. Click the Graphic Style in the palette.

Answer (score 0):

IF all the objects have the same Gradient applied to them..

Simply select all the objects and make any adjustments you wish in the **Gradient Panel**.

Common gradients can be changed in unison by merely selecting the objects.